# Hidding view with table scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm searching for idea how to implement a table view with moving view on top of it.
So the idea is something similar to navBar in facebook app. When you scroll up this (red) view is moving up and hiding, when you scroll up its going up and when you scroll down its revealed. This is not nav bar so most of the pods I've found are not working in this situation. This cannot be tableView header or section header as well. 
[image]

Comment: This explains pretty much everything: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/  the "Adanced ScrollView Techniques " video.

Answer (score 0):

You need added this view above table:

```
[self.tableView.superview insertSubview:view aboveSubview:self.tableView]
```

Or you can do it in storyboard.
When you table scroll down hide view, when up show.

```
[view setHidden:YES];
```

Also u could change table inset to the top of the superview.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.tableView.contentInset.top -,                                                                                   self.tableView.contentInset.left, self.tableView.contentInset.bottom, self.tableView.contentInset.right);
```

Comment: I want it not to cover the first row. Also I want it to move with scroll until it hiddes.

Comment: If you increase inset, table will not cover first row. View will have static position. if you want move view you can change view position when changes tableView offset.

Comment: Increasing content insets makes scroll indicator partly hidden under the red view

Comment: self.tableView.contentInset = self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets - it is scroll indicator inset

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library, it does exactly what you want to do

https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar

Comment: Its almost it, cant make it not hide navBar

Answer (score 0):

I think fast way to do it use gesture recognizers to recognize reveal and hide actions and than you can use methods like below,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [attachedView setAlpha:0.0f];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [attachedView setHidden:YES];
}];
```

and for reveal attached view

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [attachedView setAlpha:1.0f];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [attachedView setHidden:YES];
}];
```

methods will help you to hide and reveal views gently.